# How can I run a batch file from my Visual C# .NET code and retrieve the results?

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have created a getSvnUrl.bat

containing the following code

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=1-2" %%i in ('"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svn.exe" info     C:\\Code\\ServiceRouter153\\SCM\\Configs\\ServiceRouter_MIGRATION.xml') do (
    if "%%i"=="URL:" (
    set URL=%%j
    )
)
echo The result is.. %URL%
```

I would like to run this .bat from C# .NET code and be able to collect the SVN url contained the URL variable in a String variable in C#.

I tried this C# code from an 11 year old MSN blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/06/01/146375.aspx

It is not working. Is there a new way to do this?

```
    private void runSyncAndGetResults_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi =
          new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\getSvnUrl.bat");
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process listFiles;
        listFiles = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
        System.IO.StreamReader myOutput = listFiles.StandardOutput;
        listFiles.WaitForExit(2000);
        if (listFiles.HasExited)
        {
            string output = myOutput.ReadToEnd();
            this.processResults.Text = output;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is it not working? Any exception?

Comment: Why does it need to be a Batch-File ? You could run that exe file directly from c#, using similar code.

Comment: It does not need to be a batch file.  How would I do this with process?

Comment: @ThomasWeller it does work except for the line this.processResults.Text = output; I'm exactly sure what that line is doing?  Maybe it doesn't matter, but I'm curious what that line is doing the output is already a String.  What is the Text thing about

Comment: That's a textbox somewhere on a Form. Nothing to care about. Just remove it and use `output` as you like

Comment: Ok I think I get it.  This example was using some kind of click event so the .Text was to pull the text of some UI element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I ended up using in case it ever helps someone else.

```
    private string runBatchGetSvnUrl()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi =
          new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\getSvnUrl.bat");
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process listFiles;
        listFiles = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
        System.IO.StreamReader myOutput = listFiles.StandardOutput;
        listFiles.WaitForExit(2000);
        if (listFiles.HasExited)
        {
            string output = myOutput.ReadToEnd();
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            return "It didn't work.";
            //change this to throw an excetion later


        }

    }
```